# Как передать переменную в кнопку pycord?

Tags: python, классы, discord, discord.py, pycord

Упрощу ситуацию, чтобы осталась только суть вопроса. Допустим у меня есть список, например
`list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]`. При прописывании команды отправляется сообщение с 1 элементом и кнопка, которая при нажатии изменяет контент сообщение на 2 элемент и так далее. Из-за того что в Pycord кнопки делаются через класс, я не уверен как можно передать текущую позицию без совсем уж сомнительных костылей. Вариант с прочтением содержимого сообщения не подходит.

Comment: выведите аргумент за класс и дайте ему необходимые данные.

Answer (score 0):

Кнопки в Pycord необязательно делаются через класс. Вы можете просто создать объект `Button`, добавить его в объект `View` и отправить. Ниже код для вашего запроса:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(intents = discord.Intents.all())

@bot.slash_command(name = 'abcd')
async def abcd(ctx):
    list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    
    global click_counter
    click_counter = 0
    
    button = discord.ui.Button(
        label = list[click_counter], 
        style = discord.ButtonStyle.grey, 
        custom_id = list[click_counter]
    )
    
    async def callback(interaction):
        
        global click_counter
        click_counter += 1
        
        if click_counter == 4:
            button.label = 'Stop pressing'
            button.custom_id = 'nmp'
            button.disabled = True
            button.callback = None
            view = discord.ui.View(button, timeout = None)
            
            await interaction.response.edit_message(content = 'Stop pressing', view = view)
            return

        button.label = list[click_counter]
        button.custom_id = list[click_counter]
        view = discord.ui.View(button, timeout = None)
        
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content = list[click_counter], view = view)
        
    button.callback = callback
    view = discord.ui.View(button, timeout = None)
    
    await ctx.respond(content = list[click_counter], view = view)
        

bot.run('token')
```